# Name is required Nodejs API

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

I have a problem with the name is required I don't know where this problem comes from

I have no console error

---

**CODE 1:**

```js
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  prenom: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    max: 255,
    min: 3
  },
  nom: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    max: 255,
    min: 3
  },
  adresse: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    max: 255,
    min: 3
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    max: 255,
    min: 6
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    max: 1024,
    min: 6
  },
  type: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    max: 1024,
    min: 5
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});
```

---

CODE 2:

```js
// Create New User
const user = new User({
  prenom: req.body.prenom,
  nom: req.body.nom,
  adresse: req.body.adresse,
  email: req.body.email,
  password: hashedPassword,
  type: req.body.type
});
try {
  const savedUser = await user.save();
  res.send({
    user: user._id
  });
} catch (err) {
  res.status(400).send(err);
}
```

---

**ERROR Name is required**

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you've designed your schema, but didn't instanciate your model ...

In The doc : https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#models

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({...})

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema) // <--- Here
```

Answer (score 0):

No still not More information from my code :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({...});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User',userSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

I once had that issue on my dev mode. I considered dropping that collection on my DB and it worked.